# How to rotate an EditBone? is it possible

Tags: transforms, armature, bones

I have a dict of 2d data and I want to generate bones (skeleton), assuming z = 0 for translation and rotation is across z axis in given dict.

```
data = {"bones":[{"name":"root"},
{"name":"COM","parent":"root","length":35.18,"x":-128.09,"y":160.22},
{"name":"torso","parent":"COM","length":102.78,"x":127.78,"y":-116.67,"rotation":90},
{"name":"armL","parent":"torso","length":76.14,"x":62.96,"y":-39.81,"rotation":-103.29},
{"name":"armR","parent":"torso","length":92.75,"x":68.52,"y":32.4,"rotation":104.14}]}
```

here is my blender script to iterate on the dict. I can create bones.
currently placing new bone on top of each other(almost).
what I can handle is,
initial head position directly , on x and y coords
placing tail position directly via length
but

HOW to apply rotation? any ideas

Sample code for current progress..

```
import json,os,sys
from mathutils import Matrix
from mathutils import Vector
import bpy

def createBaseArmature():
    bpy.ops.object.add(type='ARMATURE',enter_editmode=True,location=(0,0,0))
    ob = bpy.context.object
    return ob
def createBones(amt,bonesData):
    print (str(len(bonesData)) + " bones found")
    for each in bonesData:
        bone = amt.edit_bones.new(each['name'])
        if 'parent' in each:
            bone.parent = amt.edit_bones[each['parent']]
            bone.head = bone.parent.tail
            rot = Matrix.Translation((0,0,0))
            bone.tail = rot * Vector ((0,0,each['length'])) + bone.head
        else:
            bone.head = (0,0,0)
            bone.tail = (0,0,1)

obj = createBaseArmature()
amt = obj.data
createBones(amt,data['bones'])
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can adjust the `head/tail/roll` directly, `EditBone`'s have a helper function for this:  [`EditBone.transform`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.types.EditBone.html#bpy.types.EditBone.transform), which I *think* is the most direct answer to your question, just pass a rotation matrix to it.

This is simply a python helper function, see [the code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py;e60fb0fd294577948f8ce0f07817b98d1b3024fe%24335).